# Group common search result headlines

Tags: python, ruby, search

I have an array of several news headlines ( just strings ) that I have retrieved from multiple news sources ( some that my company pays for ).  Often the headlines are similar, but do not match word for word.  I would like to try and bucket them similarly to how google news does it.

Is there an algorithm out there to do this?  I can use ruby or python for this script.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Ruby, look at the [text](http://text.rubyforge.org/) gem, specifically the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between two strings.

Comment: Thanks Phrogz.  This did the trick.  I'll also add this link to a wiki book page that has several implementations in differente languages: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance